# how to run the .o file after make

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I have been trying to run a c++ program from https://github.com/rinon/Simple-Homomorphic-Encryption

As specified in the `README` I have run the following commands,

```
make

make test

make demo
```

Now, I have the following files in my directory,

```
zakirhussain@zakirhussain-K52F:~/Simple-Homomorphic-Encryption$ ls
circuit.cpp             demo_vote_counter.cpp  fully_homomorphic.cpp  main.o                 security_settings.h     test_suite.o  utilities.o
circuit.h               demo_vote_counter.h    fully_homomorphic.h    makefile               security_settings.o     type_defs.h
circuit.o               demo_vote_counter.o    fully_homomorphic.o    README                 test_fully_homomorphic  utilities.c
demo_fully_homomorphic  fully_homomorphic      main.cpp               security_settings.cpp  test_suite.cpp          utilities.h
```

Could someone help me with running `demo_vote_counter.o` file?

Comment: You don't "run" a `.o` file.  That's an object file, which is used to build executables.  From the above list it looks like you want to run either `./demo_fully_homomorphic`, `./fully_homomorphic`, or `./test_fully_homomorphic`.

Comment: do `ls -F` and look for the asterisks. Those are executables.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

An *object file* (`.o`) is not executable. You want to be running `./demo_fully_homomorphic` (e.g. the file without extension). Make sure you have execute permissions (`chmod a+x demo_fully_homomorphic`).

Answer (score 10):

You can not run a `.o` file. This is an object file and has to be linked into the final executable. A `.o` file is usually lacking additional libraries, which are added at the linking stage.

Looking at your outoput I would assume that one of `demo_fully_homomorphic`, `test_fully_homomorphic` or `fully_homomorphic` are the executables that you can run.

Answer (score 4):

I think I am late, but the code below maybe helpful for someone, I guess.

Using cd into your folder contains the c/c++ file, then compile it.

```
gcc my_test.c -o my_test
```

Complied file will be generated. Then still in same folder. Run the command.

```
./my_test
```

Comment: Yes, "Complied file"

Comment: Yours is the only answer that comes close to answering the OP. He is asking what steps he needs to take to run his program. Compiling is a necessary step and only you attempt to give that step. My question: there is no file listed in the form *.c except utilities.c. Would it be possible to give the exact command needed for the OP? Or is there no way to determine that from the directory of files that he displayed?

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned in several other answers, you can execute a binary file and not the object file. However, Just in case, if what you want is to display the contents of object file in readable format?

```
$>objdump -d object_filename.o
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't run the object file. It has to be linked first to make an executable.

As I see there is a "demo_fully_homomorphic" "fully_homomorphic" and a "test_fully_homomorphic" in your directory. Those are your linked executables, you may execute them with ./[executable_name]

Answer (score 0):

In this case the executable is called `demo_fully_homomorphic`, try

```
./demo_fully_homomorphic
```